# Image contained in div not centering with margin: auto

Tags: css

I have the following html and css code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <section class="top">
                <div id="quote"><a href="contact.html"><p>Request a quote</p></a></div>
                <div class="arrow"><img src="icons/top-icon.png" alt=""></div>
            </section>
</body>
</html>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

a {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
.top {
    height: 3.2em;    
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(255,214,94); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,214,94,1) 0%, rgba(254,191,4,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,214,94,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(254,191,4,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,214,94,1) 0%,rgba(254,191,4,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,214,94,1) 0%,rgba(254,191,4,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,214,94,1) 0%,rgba(254,191,4,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,214,94,1) 0%,rgba(254,191,4,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffd65e', endColorstr='#febf04',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left :0;
    z-index: 10;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f9e555;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #555;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #555;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #555;
    }
.top div#quote {
    width: 20em;
    background: rgb(254,252,234); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,252,234,1) 0%, rgba(241,218,54,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(254,252,234,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(241,218,54,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,252,234,1) 0%,rgba(241,218,54,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,252,234,1) 0%,rgba(241,218,54,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,252,234,1) 0%,rgba(241,218,54,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,252,234,1) 0%,rgba(241,218,54,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fefcea', endColorstr='#f1da36',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
.top div#quote p {
    color: #f2572a;
    height: 3.5em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;        
    }
.top div#quote a {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    }
.top div#quote p:hover {
    color: #ed3419;
    }    
.arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    }
```

There are 2 problems here: the first one is that the "Request a quote div" is larger than the 3.2em defined in the css and the second one is that if I delete the text-aling: center in .top styling the image underneath the quote div will not stay centered. I have tried to position relative the .arrow div and position absolute the img icon, but it does not work as the div disappears completely. Any other ideas?
​

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the `.arrow` element has a default width of 100%, setting `margin: 0 auto` has no effect horizontally. And since `img` is an inline element, it won't work on that either. You need to either set an explicit width on the `.arrow` element, or set `display: block` and `margin: 0 auto` on the `img` element.

Comment: this works, thx. I tried the margin: 0 auto; on the image element with display: inline or inline-block on arrow element, but it did not work. I did not think of puting the display:block on the img element though.

Answer (score 2):

The "Request a quote" div is larger because its height is relative to its font size. [`em`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#font-relative-lengths) is based on the current width of the letter `M` (at least in [classic typography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_%28typography%29)). Since you change the `font-size` in your elements `3.2em` in `.top` isn't the same as `3.2em` in `.top div#quote p`.

Even if you won't change the `font-size` the values still differ (`3.2em` in `.top`, `3.5em` in `.top div#quote p`).

You should get rid of all `padding-top`s, `padding-bottom`s, `margin-top`s and `margin-bottom`s instead and simply use `height:100%`.

#### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>
        <section class="top">
            <p class="quote"><a href="contact.html">Request a quote</a></p>
            <img class="arrow" src="icons/top-icon.png" alt="Arrow"></div>
        </section>
    </header>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    z-index: 10;

    height: 3.2em;

    background: rgb(255,214,94); /* Old browsers */
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,214,94,1) 0%,rgba(254,191,4,1) 100%); /* W3C */    

    text-align: center;

    border-bottom: 1px solid #f9e555;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #555;
}

.top p.quote {
    width: 20em;
    height:100%;  

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;

    color: #f2572a;    
    font-size: 1.6em;
    line-height:2.1em;

    background: rgb(254,252,234); /* Old browsers */
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,252,234,1) 0%,rgba(241,218,54,1) 100%); /* W3C */
}

.top p.quote a{
    color: #f2572a;
}

.top p.quote a:hover{
    color: #ed3419;
}    
.arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
}

/* gradient and other vendor specific quirks */
.top{
    /* background rules */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,214,94,1) 0%, rgba(254,191,4,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,214,94,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(254,191,4,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,214,94,1) 0%,rgba(254,191,4,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,214,94,1) 0%,rgba(254,191,4,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,214,94,1) 0%,rgba(254,191,4,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffd65e', endColorstr='#febf04',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    /* vendor specific box shadows */    
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #555;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #555;
}

.top p.quote{    
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,252,234,1) 0%, rgba(241,218,54,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(254,252,234,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(241,218,54,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,252,234,1) 0%,rgba(241,218,54,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,252,234,1) 0%,rgba(241,218,54,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,252,234,1) 0%,rgba(241,218,54,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */    
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fefcea', endColorstr='#f1da36',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qJHzz/1/)

Comment: I see, than how could I go defining a larger font-size, and still keep the 2 elements equal by defining the height in em?

Comment: For example, you could use a proper markup. A `<p>aragraph` is a block. It should contain an `<a>nchor`, not the other way round. It doesn't need a parent `<div>`. You can set its  `class="quote"`. Try to keep the HTML as simple as possible, then `height:100%` will work wonders.

Comment: you are right, its much more logical this way. however the problem still rests with the line-height in this solution, I can't define line height to be the same as the .top and this was important as to center the element verticaly.

Comment: @viktor: To achieve a perfect vertical alignment the product of `line-height` and `font-size` of the child `<p>` has to be the same as the `height` of the parent `<div>`, e.g. `3.5 ≈ 2.1 * 1.6` (no paddings/margins included).